# Running pythontex from TeX using \immediate\write18 fails

Tags: shell-escape, pythontex

Running `pythontex` from TeX using `\immediate\write18` fails, for reasons that are unclear to me. See my example file below.

Running

```
pdflatex -shell-escape p.tex
```

does not produce the `pycode.txt` file as desired.
However, running

```
pythontex p.tex
```

does. The logs don't give any obvious indication of failure.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% p.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[runall]{pythontex}
\begin{pycode}
f = open("pycode.txt", 'w')
f.write("Hello, this is Python writing from TeX.")
f.close()
\end{pycode}
\immediate\write18{pythontex \jobname.tex}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pythontex` writes code and related information to a tempfile `.pytxcode`, which is then used to execute the code later. This tempfile is opened as soon as `pythontex` is loaded, and is closed `\AfterEndDocument`. If you try to run `pythontex` in the preamble, it will read an incomplete tempfile, and as a result give an error about the tempfile format.

What you want to do is run `pythontex` *after* the tempfile is completed and closed.  Using `\AfterEndDocument{\immediate\write18{pythontex \jobname.tex}}` works for me.  Another option would be to run the `\write18` command *before* loading `pythontex`, perhaps with a conditional to detect the presence of the tempfile.

Comment: Thanks very much. That works. But I didn't notice any error about the tempfile format. "perhaps with a conditional to detect the presence of the tempfile." Why is that necessary?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Recent versions of `pythontex` should give a message like "The .pytxcode file appears to have an outdated format or be invalid". A conditional could be useful on the first compile, when the tempfile doesn't exist; in that case, there's no need to run `pythontex`, though doing so won't cause problems (`pythontex` will just exit with an error).